# Sql - merge two query to make it rows

Tags: c#, mysql

i want to get the disease total and last week total from this table(tb_data):

```
P_ID   Disease                Date
1      A                      2016-10-11
2      A                      2016-10-11
3      A                      2016-10-14
4      A                      2016-10-19
```

while i have query like this:

```
SELECT Disease AS DT,
COUNT(P_ID) AS PT
FROM tb_data
GROUP BY Disease
union
SELECT Disease AS DLW,
COUNT(P_ID) AS PLW
FROM tb_data
WHERE Date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND Date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
GROUP BY Disease
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1;
```

what i want as a result is like this

```
DT  PT DLW PLW
A   4  A   3
```

not this

```
DT  PT
A   4
A   3
```

because i want my program read this:

```
foreach (DataRow kolom in table.Rows)
                {
                    Total = kolom["PT"].ToString();
                    Lastweek = kolom["PLW"].ToString();
                }
labelTotal.Text = Total;
labelLastWeek.Text = Lastweek;
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think conditional aggregation is what you need.

```
select disease as dt,
         sum(1) as pt,
         disease as dlw,
         sum(case when date between curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY and curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY then 1 else 0 end) as plw
from    tb_data
group   by disease;
```

Result

```
+------+------+------+------+
| dt   | pt   | dlw  | plw  |
+------+------+------+------+
| A    |    4 | A    |    3 |
+------+------+------+------+
```